# Currencies, exchange rates, how to make proper relations?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple currencies (they are not real) and exchange rates between them. E.g.
**currency_a**, **currency_b**, **1.5**
If i need to exchange **A** -> **B** i simply multiply value by **1.5**, or if i need to
exchange **B** -> **A** i divide value by **1.5**.
How can i properly express this in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would simply have a conversion table with two columns as a conversion factor:

```
from_currency  to_currency    rate     
      A            B          1.5
      B            A          0.66667
```

In this method, the rates are multiplicative and both pairs are stored.  This should make it easy to use.

For performance, you want a primary key on `(from_currency, to_currency)`.

Comment: What if i use many to many relation on the same table instead of this approach? Or it is a bad idea?

Comment: @xxx_coder_noscope . . . I don't know what your comment is referring to.

Comment: what would be primary key in your case?

Answer (score 0):

That approach IS a M:M it's just that both sides reference the same parent table. The PK remains the same, but each should also be an FK. A sample layout maybe something like:

```
create table currency ( 
             id_currency serial 
           , code        text
           , name        text
           , constraint  currency_pk
                         primary key (id_currency)
           , constraint  currency_bk 
                         unique (code)
           ) ; 
create table currency_conversion(
             from_currency integer 
           , to_currency   integer
           , rate          number(9,5)
           , constraint    currency_conversion_pk
                           primary key (from_currency,to_currency)
           , constraint    from_conversion_2_currency_fk
                           foreign key (from_currency)
                           references currency(id_currency)
           , constraint    to_conversion_2_currency_fk
                           foreign key (to_currency)
                           references currency(id_currency)
          );
```